# How can we Cucumber file Parallel execution using Ant

Tags: java, ant, cucumber, hacl

I want to execute cucumber feature file parallel, I am using ant build file for build the application below is the sample cucumber file I am reading the data from excel sheet, If excel sheet has 10 data, I want split the data into 2 parts and each part 5 data and execute that 2 parts parallel. In cucumber how can we execute parallel without maven plugin and TestNg, here I am using ant file for build, How can we implement this? Through Java or multi threading can we implement this?

```
Scenario: Read excel files data 
Given Launch mainframe application with "Host" "Port" 
Given Login credentials with "UserId" "Pwd" 
Then I want to read excel data from "abc.xlsx" and process 
Then I logout`
```

Comment: How does your question relate to `mainframe`?

Comment: My application is Mainframe application using HACL library